# I want to configure static route on my ubuntu vm but there's no network/interfaces file at all

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet

I don't know why there is no /etc/network/interfaces file yet I can still get to internet:
it's shown like this:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ cd /etc/network/
osboxes@osboxes:/etc/network$ ls
if-down.d  if-post-down.d  if-pre-up.d  if-up.d
```

below is my ifconfig show:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ ifconfig
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.109.132  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.109.255
        inet6 fe80::4b56:f1d8:ad1a:51b0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:fe:5f:fa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 178  bytes 62290 (62.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 181  bytes 28488 (28.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  base 0x2000  

ens34: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.123.48  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.123.255
        inet6 fe80::4cc0:a44a:116c:acdf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:fe:5f:04  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 50  bytes 7803 (7.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 75  bytes 9760 (9.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  base 0x2080  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 216  bytes 18223 (18.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 216  bytes 18223 (18.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The first one is NAT mode while the second one is bridged from my local network;
I want to add static route using the ens34 interface,
So where should I add an static route, can anyone tell me, realy thank you!!!

Comment: In recent Ubuntu versions, networking is handled by Network Manager in desktop installations and by netplan for server installations. Which version do you have? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I use desktop version and I now know just config from the GUI which is just clear,thank you